# Is it possible to configure additional folders in arbitrary locations to serve static resource in a war file

Tags: java, tomcat, war

By default, files under web-app are served, in an application container like tomcat, as static resources.  So if I save a file like helloworld.html in those I can view it from my browser at

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/helloworld.html
```

Is it possible to configure additional folders other than web-app to serve static content.  I would prefer to do this from within the war file itself instead of having to configure it on a tomcat-wide way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: WAR file is just a Web application ARchive, a container that hold all application files and folder including special files and directories (like WEB-INF, web.xml etc). You can have as many folders inside it as you like, nesting them as you like. What's the problem? Or do you want to serve static files **outside** WAR?

Answer (score 0):

[Maven's war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) is a good fit here. This offers several configuration options when building the war so it'll be independent of your web server.

And [an example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) where a different directory can be hosted as you suggest

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>resource2</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Here's an another example they give where a different webapp folder can be used.

```
<project>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy/directory</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
</project>
```